# Creating Hybrid pages with Gatsby.js

Tags: gatsby, progressive-web-apps

Recently I have explored to create a PWA using Gatsby.js. What I intended was to have

1. home page
2. Product List page
3. Product display page

I could easily do a home page, since the content of this page is almost static.

I had product list page which has filters on the left. Once I choose filters the filtered product list will be shown by hitting the shopify API. I feel this cannot be done with Gatsby using their GraphQL layer since it fetches data at build time and it can't handle real time data as such.So I believe I should fetch data from React only and manage the app from there. Similarly I have a pagination which would be difficult to build since it has to make request every time we go the next page.

My question would be how can we think in an optimal way to build these kinds of app using gatsby.

Comment: I was also looking for a example with gatsby and pwa and found this. Maybe it helps you too. https://github.com/snipcart/gatsby-pwa-demo

Answer (score 0):

Pretty broad question,IMO plus no code or app/file architecture ideas or plan layouts?? I cant layout the whole architecture, dev-ops & design for you. But I have built an application dealing with relatively similar environments.

Use CI/CD practices with a solid CMS as a Data source, `gatsby-source-contentful` and most importantly **lambda** this is your best friend.

Think about some fancy file structure, create custom build commands in `package.json`,

example:`build": "gatsby build && netlify-lambda build lambda-src"`

This way the usual gatsby src file and lambda src file, are separated. Here is a great tool, for this project https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda#readme.

Comment: thanks to avoid the excess of acronyms for the readability of your answer